# Skype speakers output muted

Tags: pulseaudio, skype

Whenever I login my speakers volume are automatically reduced to zero. During calls other people are able to hear me but I don’t hear anyone. Speakers muted icon keeps appearing, and even after I push it’s volume up, it stays muted and nailed to zero. I am new to Linux and not very good with prompt commands. I tried all the solutions from google searches on this topic. I opened alsamixer in terminal and checked all the volumes. There seems to be 2 sound cards: HDA ATI HDMI which has no output according to alsa, and HD-Audio Generic which I am using. This dude had the same problem and its solved but some of the commands do not apply to my prompt https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=231283

#### Screenshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please import the screenshots into the image upload tool here. Also, instead of saying you “tried all of the google searches” (hard as that is to believe), just list the things you tried in the question and the results.